# Как с помощью PDFBox-а (Java) сохранить картинку из PDF файла?

Tags: java, изображения, get, pdf

Есть pdf файлы в которых есть отсканированный документ + распознанный в нём текст. 
pdfRenderer.renderImage  и pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI дают на выходе картинку из распознанного текста, а нужна именно отсканированная картинка (сам растр).

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён путём добавления levigo-jbig2-imageio. После этого pdfRenderer.renderImage начал возвращать саму картинку, а не рендер текста.